# "Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll()" em PDO

Tags: php, pdo, fetchall

O seguinte código apresenta um erro de método indefinido na linha:

> `$result = ($exec!==false)?$exec->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC):$exec;`

```
public function getConnection(){
            global $conn;
            $this->conn = $conn;
            if (!is_object($this->conn)) {
                $this->conn = parent::connect();
            }
        }

        public function select($qry){
            self::getConnection();
            $result = false;
            try{
                $exec = parent::execQuery($qry,$this->conn);
            }catch (PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
            $result = ($exec!==false)?$exec->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC):$exec;
            return $result;
        }
```

> UPDATE:
>
> 1.0 - Segue abaixo a função **execQuery()** que está na *parent class* `connect`

```
public function execQuery($qry,$con){
        $exec = $con->query($qry);

        if($exec === false){
            //ob_clean();
            throw new Exception($qry."<br>".$con->error);
        }else{
            return $exec;
        }
    }
```

> UPDATE:
>
> 1.1 - Segue abaixo o `print_r($this->conn)`

```
mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 0 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.5.5-10.1.9-MariaDB [server_version] => 50505 [stat] => Uptime: 235 Threads: 1 Questions: 10 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 1 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 12 Queries per second avg: 0.042 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 9 [warning_count] => 0 ) mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 0 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.5.5-10.1.9-MariaDB [server_version] => 50505 [stat] => Uptime: 235 Threads: 1 Questions: 10 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 1 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 12 Queries per second avg: 0.042 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 9 [warning_count] => 0 )
```

### Porque este erro acontece?

- PDO está habilitado
- PHP Version 5.6.15

Comment: Tem algo bem errado aí, `mysqli_result::fetchAll()`?

Comment: Pois é, mano. kkkkkkk TAMBÉM NÃO SEI!

Comment: Da uma olhada em `execQuery()`

Comment: rray, editada..

Comment: No select, da um print_r em `$this->conn` e `$exec` ou tem variável sendo sobrescrita ou algum arquivo sendo puxado errado.

Comment: rray: `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 5 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) `

Comment: Não é PDO, mysqli, tem algo errado nos seus arquivos.

Comment: Vou colocar acima o do $this->conn

Comment: Ta editado, rray

Comment: Fica mais fácil você localizar tudo que é "mysqli" nos seus arquivos, e consequentemente achar o erro. Praticamente todos os editores de código bons tem uma pesquisa em arquivos.

Comment: Tudo está em **mysqli** `$con = @new mysqli(self::DB_HOST, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS, self::DB_NOME);`

Comment: Porque esse erro ocorre? Versão do PHP/?

Comment: O PDO tem o `fetchAll()` e o MySQLi a partir do php5.3 tem o `fetch_all()`

Comment: Ou é mysqli ou é PDO... Você precisa escolher qual vai usar, não tem como misturar pedaços de uma na outra. Se abrir a conexão com PDO, tem que usar só as funções ou métodos do PDO, da mesma forma, se abriu com mysqli, tem que usar só os do mysqli.

Comment: Bacco, isso explica a confusão ou o problema?

Comment: Mas eles está reclamando do mysqlnd e não do `PDO`, o `mysqlnd` está ativado?

Comment: @deFreitas ele nao estava usando PDO, veja a linha nos comentários: `$con = @new mysqli(self::DB_HOST, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS, self::DB_NOME);`

Comment: @Bacco é exatamente isso que estou dizendo, ele disse que está com o PDO ativado mas isso não faz diferença porque ele está usando o mysqlnd

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido definindo um único tipo de conexão para:

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::DB_HOST.';dbname='.self::DB_NOME, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS);
```